# Remove "-" character from dictionary keys

Tags: swift

I want remove the character "-" and replace by "". However it is a dictionary, I do not know how to do it?

```
var arrays: [String:[String]] = ["2017-08-21":["red"], "2017-08-20":["red"], "2017-08-19":["red"], "2017-08-18":["red"], "2017-08-17":["red"]]
print(arrays)
```

Comment: i can't make by hand because the dictionary is from json file

Comment: Can you please add examples of what you have tried?

Comment: sory You want i send what?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution is to iterate over the key-value pairs in your dictionary and create a new dictionary with the new keys and old values.

```
var arrays: [String:[String]] = ["2017-08-21":["red"], "2017-08-20":["red"], "2017-08-19":["red"], "2017-08-18":["red"], "2017-08-17":["red"]]
var formattedDictionary = [String:[String]]()
for (key, value) in arrays {
    formattedDictionary[key.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")] = value
}
print(formattedDictionary)
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Swift 4

As Swift 4 is just around the corner, I'll add a Swift 4 viable alternative.

Using the new [`init(uniqueKeysWithValues:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894798-init) initializer of `Dictionary`, we may replace the content of the dictionary `arrays` with a new dictionary based solely on the key-modified key-value pairs from the original dictionary. E.g.:

```
import Foundation

var arrays = ["2017-08-21": ["red"], 
              "2017-08-20": ["red"], 
              "2017-08-19": ["red"], 
              "2017-08-18": ["red"], 
              "2017-08-17": ["red"]]

arrays = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: arrays
    .map { ($0.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: ""), $1) })

print(arrays)
/* ["20170820": ["red"], 
    "20170817": ["red"], 
    "20170818": ["red"], 
    "20170821": ["red"], 
    "20170819": ["red"]] */
```

Note the import of `Foundation` to get access to [`replacingOccurrences(of:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412937-replacingoccurrences) of `NSString` (available to Swift:s `String` via bridging).

---

Alternatively, implementing the `Dictionary` key-modification logic above as an extension to `Dictionary`:

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func updateKeys(_ transform: (Key) -> Key) {
        self = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: 
                          self.map { (transform($0), $1) })
    }
}
```

Allowing "in-place" (logically, at least) modification of the keys of a dictionary by some supplied transformation:

```
var arrays = ["2017-08-21": ["red"], 
              "2017-08-20": ["red"], 
              "2017-08-19": ["red"], 
              "2017-08-18": ["red"], 
              "2017-08-17": ["red"]]

arrays.updateKeys { $0.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "") }

print(arrays)
/* ["20170820": ["red"], 
    "20170817": ["red"], 
    "20170818": ["red"], 
    "20170821": ["red"], 
    "20170819": ["red"]] */
```

Just note that applying the `transform` to two different unique keys could naturally yield the same key result, so we probably want to modify the extension above to take this into account:

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func updateKeys(_ transform: (Key) -> Key,
            uniquingKeysWith combine: (Value, Value) -> Value) {
        self = Dictionary(map { (transform($0), $1) },
                          uniquingKeysWith: combine)
    }
}
```

Applied e.g. in the following example, where `(1)` and `(2)` keys are unique, but resolve to the same `String` after applying the `transform` used in the example above.

```
var arrays = ["2017-08-21": ["red"], // (1)
              "20170821": ["blue"],  // (2)
              "2017-08-20": ["red"], 
              "2017-08-19": ["red"], 
              "2017-08-18": ["red"], 
              "2017-08-17": ["red"]]

arrays.updateKeys({$0.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "") },
                 uniquingKeysWith: { $0 + $1 })

print(arrays)
/* ["20170820": ["red"], 
    "20170817": ["red"], 
    "20170818": ["red"], 
    "20170821": ["red", "blue"], 
    "20170819": ["red"]] */
```

Here, we choose to concatenate `Value` arrays in case `transform` resolve two (or more) keys to the same new key.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a quick solution:

```
let dictionaryWithOldKeys: [String : [String]] = ["2017-08-21":["red"], "2017-08-20":["red"], "2017-08-19":["red"], "2017-08-18":["red"], "2017-08-17":["red"]]

var dictionaryWithNewKeys: [String : [String]] = [:]

for item in dictionaryWithOldKeys {    
    dictionaryWithNewKeys.updateValue(item.value, forKey: item.key.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "."))
}

print(dictionaryWithNewKeys)
```